# ActiveRecord changed? flag doesn't report changes in associated children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got the following situation with ActiveRecord (in Rails 2.3.8):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end

class Document <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Now, in a controller I want to direct the user differently depending on whether or not they made changes to existing records, e.g.

```
@order.attributes = params[:order]
if @order.changed?
  # save order
  # redirect one place
else
  # redirect another place
end
```

For that I want to use the changed? flag.  It turns out that @order.changed? does not query the children.

I tried to implement that via an association proxy method on the has_many :documents association, like so:

```
  has_many :documents do
    def changed?
      any? {|doc| doc.changed?}
    end
  end
```

But this has the unintended side-effect that it loads the associated documents from disk, which apparently wipes out any changes that were made in the nested attributes assignment in @order.attributes = params[:order]  This either seems an intentional design decision in Rails, but then how to solve it? Or is it a feature gap?

Thoughts?

Wolf

Comment: require 'dm-core'
    require 'dm-migrations'
    require 'dm-accepts_nested_attributes'
    class Order
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id, Serial
      has n, :documents
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
    end

    class Document
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :id, Serial
      property :foo, String
      belongs_to :order

    end

    DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::memory:')
    DataMapper.auto_migrate!

    @o = Order.create
    @o.attributes = {'documents' => [{'foo' => 'bar'}]}
    @o.documents.any? {|doc| doc.dirty?}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might have a look at the source of [nested_records_changed_for_autosave](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/nested_records_changed_for_autosave%3F).

It is not exactly what you want, but it has clues about how to do it. Especially [association_instance_get](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/association_instance_get) which "Gets the specified association instance if it responds to :loaded?, nil otherwise."

Comment: Thanks for that bit of advice. That lead us down the right path of inquiry.
It turned out that our actual issue was related to the fact that any in-memory objects created from nested attributes were overwritten in various validation rules and before_save hooks that inadvertently loaded the associations from disk, in particular :validates_presence_of :documents in the Order model will hose the use of nested attributes for updates.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to detect whether an object had its association changed from a persisted object to a non-persisted one. The `changes` method would return the new value as a blank string, as it expects an ID. `object.association(attribute.gsub '_id', '').target` did the trick for me!